# Can I reference to same database table in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a very interesting question, can I reference to same database table in Laravel?

I have a model Account that has table accounts.

An account can have multiple subaccounts. I want a hierarchy of accounts

```
Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('code');
    $table->integer('accounttype_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('accounttypes')->index();
    $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('accounts')->index();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I hope I am clear with my question. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to. However, make the column nullable, or else every account will be foreced to be a subaccount.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: Yeah! of course, you can.
Hierarchy in a model is a useful feature that might be used in every application. But it's better to name the column as "parent_id". But the way that you defined the relationship is OK.

In your model, you can add two relationships called "children" and "parent".
Parent method should return a "BelongsTo" relationship with the same class and also children can return a "HasMany" Relationship.

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class,'parent_id');
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class,'parent_id');
}
```

If you want more than one Model with hierarchy it's better to create a Trait (Ex: HasHierarchy) that includes children() and parent() methods. Whenever you want hierarchy you can just add `use HasHierarchy;` at the beginning of your class.